# Unity - Touch rotate camera along X axis

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a unity *C#* script working that will rotate the camera around the X axis in a 3D environment. Currently, it flips the screen making my terrain look like it is hanging upside down. I'm just trying to get the camera to rotate on the X axis instead. Below is what I currently have.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TouchCamera : MonoBehaviour {
Vector2?[] oldTouchPositions = {
    null,
    null
};
Vector2 oldTouchVector;
float oldTouchDistance;

void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount == 0) {
        oldTouchPositions[0] = null;
        oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
    }
    else if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
        if (oldTouchPositions[0] == null || oldTouchPositions[1] != null) {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = null;
        }
        else {
            Vector2 newTouchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPosition) * camera.orthographicSize / camera.pixelHeight * 2f));

            oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPosition;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (oldTouchPositions[1] == null) {
            oldTouchPositions[0] = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            oldTouchPositions[1] = Input.GetTouch(1).position;
            oldTouchVector = (Vector2)(oldTouchPositions[0] - oldTouchPositions[1]);
            oldTouchDistance = oldTouchVector.magnitude;
        }
        else {
            Vector2 screen = new Vector2(camera.pixelWidth, camera.pixelHeight);

            Vector2[] newTouchPositions = {
                Input.GetTouch(0).position,
                Input.GetTouch(1).position
            };
            Vector2 newTouchVector = newTouchPositions[0] - newTouchPositions[1];
            float newTouchDistance = newTouchVector.magnitude;

            transform.position += transform.TransformDirection((Vector3)((oldTouchPositions[0] + oldTouchPositions[1] - screen) * camera.orthographicSize / screen.y));
            transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f));
            camera.orthographicSize *= oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance;
            transform.position -= transform.TransformDirection((newTouchPositions[0] + newTouchPositions[1] - screen) * camera.orthographicSize / screen.y);

            oldTouchPositions[0] = newTouchPositions[0];
            oldTouchPositions[1] = newTouchPositions[1];
            oldTouchVector = newTouchVector;
            oldTouchDistance = newTouchDistance;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to rotate it around (like a character turning its head), in the x-z plain, then you wanted to rotate it around the y axis, not the x.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to make a raycast shoot out the center of the camera and when it collided with something, set that as the pivot point. Then I rotated the camera around said pivot point. Example below...

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, 300)){}
   float distanceToGround = hit.distance;
   var pivotPoint = hit.point;

// -------- Rotation ---------
transform.RotateAround(pivotPoint, Vector3.up,Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Clamp((oldTouchVector.y * newTouchVector.x - oldTouchVector.x * newTouchVector.y) / oldTouchDistance / newTouchDistance, -1f, 1f)) / 0.0174532924f);

//---------------------------------------------------------
```